# Too much whitespace on setting org-mode tags

Tags: org-mode, whitespace

If I create the following in an `org-mode` buffer:

```
* one
** two
** three
```

then move point to the line containing "two" and do `C-c C-c spam <RET>`, I get this:

```
* one
** two                                                                :spam:
** three
```

Why all that whitespace between "two" and ":spam:"?  Can I stop org-mode from inserting it somehow?

Comment: I believe the default keybinding for tag is `C-c C-q`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The variable `org-tags-column` controls the distance of tags at the end of the heading. To have just one space, the original poster may wish to consider using:

```
(setq org-tags-column 0)
```

To apply the changes on an existing org file, use [`C-u C-c C-q`](https://superuser.com/a/772684/486288)

The doc-string for `org-tags-column`, which can be seen by typing `M-x describe-variable RET org-tags-column RET` states as follows:

"*The column to which tags should be indented in a headline. If this number is positive, it specifies the column. If it is negative, it means that the tags should be flushright to that column. For example, -80 works well for a normal 80 character screen. When 0, place tags directly after headline text, with only one space in between.*"